# C++ how to make a service self-update on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, dpkg

I have a fairly complex application with several components designed to keep each other running. It's supposed to be run in as a demon with superuser privileges. (Currently testing on Ubuntu 20.04)

Now I'm trying to implement a self-update feature. The program is supposed to download a .deb file from the internet and run the self-update process. The code for the self-updating part is this

```
template <std::size_t N>
int execvp(const char* file, const char* const (&argv)[N])
{
  assert((N > 0) && (argv[N - 1] == nullptr));

  return execvp(file, const_cast<char* const*>(argv));
}

err_t SoftUpdater::_installServiceUpdate(const std::string &file_path) {
  const char* const cmd[] = { "dpkg", "-i", file_path.c_str() , NULL};
  int pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0)
  {
      execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
      DBG(E, ":(, %i, %s", errno, strerror(errno));

      exit(1);
  }
  else if (pid > 0)
  {
  }
  else
  {
      DBG(E, ":(((");
  }

  return E_OK;
}
```

The update file is valid and updates properly if I run in from console. However when I  run it from within the service it get stuck updating. Calling `systemctl status` nets the following response

```
myservice.service - MyService daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: deactivating (final-sigterm) since Tue 2022-10-25 12:31:53 MSK; 16s ago
    Process: 38160 ExecStart=/opt/myservice/sbin/myservicedsp (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 38160 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 9448)
     Memory: 54.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/myservice.service
             ├─38182 dpkg -i /tmp/07080415-acf7-4404-a086-edd3ca743a22.deb
             ├─38191 /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/myservice.prerm upgrade 1.1.5-ubuntu
             └─38192 systemctl stop myservice

oct 25 12:31:51 user-VirtualBox myservicedsp[38182]: dpkg: warning: downgrading myservice from 1.1.7-ubuntu to 1.1.5-ubuntu
oct 25 12:31:53 user-VirtualBox myservicedsp[38182]: (Reading database ... 216528 files and directories currently installed.)
oct 25 12:31:53 user-VirtualBox myservicedsp[38182]: Preparing to unpack .../07080415-acf7-4404-a086-edd3ca743a22.deb ...
oct 25 12:31:53 user-VirtualBox myservicedsp[38164]: terminate called without an active exception
oct 25 12:31:53 user-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopping MyService daemon...
```

And in a minute it fails due to timeout/

So it seems the service tries to stop itself and can't until it stops. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: To be honest: I think you're barking up the wrong tree here. If you're deploying to Debian based systems, provide your updates through an *apt* repository, which you'd add to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, that way your service can be maintained through the regular system update/upgrade mechanism, including keeping track of dependencies.

Comment: One of the constriants for my software is to be able to update the clients (which I am developing) by server command. And this server is supposed to manage the packages

Comment: If you can't update while you're running, then you need to start a separate update process. This makes more sense for modularity anyway.

Comment: @WereWind: Then make this "server command" `apt update; apt install ${YOUR_PROGRAM}` . Seriously, why burden yourself with implementing a procedure that is finicky and already has been solved for you? Also your server should *never* run with superuser privileges. There's exactly one special case superuser daemons are required, and if you have to ask which case that is, you're by definition not qualified to develop software that should run with superuser privileges. Disregarding this advice leads to very severe security vulnerabilities!